# How to compare 2d array effectively

Tags: arrays, c, algorithm, comparison

Here is a 2d array here

```
{ {0.3072, 1.1262, 1.5706},
  {0.5068, 1.0630, 0.9470},
  {0.2470, 0.6872, 1.9626},
  {1.0686, 1.1348, 1.7506},
  {1.2874, 1.5664, 0.2470},
  {0.9072, 0.6268, 0.6684},
  {1.3164, 0.6506, 1.8462},
  {0.9072, 0.6268, 0.8706},
  {0.3072, 1.1262, 1.5706} }
```

I need to compare each row base on the following conditions:

1. All coordinate of point a is smaller than or equal to their corresponding coordinate of point b.
2. there exists at least one coordinate of point a that is strictly smaller than its corresponding coordinate of point b.

If the conditions are true, then I will delete point b. Here are some examples:

1. After the comparison between point 1 and point 4, point 4 will be deleted. Because all coordinate of point 1 are smaller than their corresponding coordinate of point 4.
2. After the comparison between point 6 and point 8, point 8 will be deleted. Because coordinate 3 of point 6 is smaller than corresponding coordinate of point 8, although their other two coordinates have the same values.
3. After the comparison between point 1 and point 2, no point will be deleted. Because coordinates 1 of point 1 is smaller than corresponding coordinates of point 2, but coordinates 2 and coordinates 3 of point 1 are greater than corresponding coordinates of point 2 and vice versa.
4. After the comparison between point 1 and point 9, no point will be deleted. Because all coordinates of them are equivalent.

From the above 2d array, I will delete point 4,7,8.

My attempt:
I'm using a nested loop to do the comparison between all the points

```
for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < N; j++){
            int sum = 0;
            for(int k = 0; k < 3; k++){
                if(point[i][k] <= point[j][k])
                    sum++;
            }
            if(sum == 3)
                ... // delete point[j]
        }
    }
```

This attempt works, but it's not efficient, the big-o notation of it is O(n^3).
Is there any effective algorithm that can do this comparison?

Comment: The cost for your algorithm is not O(n^3) but O(n^2) (if the number of columns is fixed) or O(n^2 m) (m is the number of columns).

Comment: The code you posted doesn't check the second condition. In fact it will delete all points because it compares points with themselves.

Comment: Is the number of columns fixed (=3)? Or else what are the constraints?

Comment: If it was possible to sort the points globally, you could sort them in O(n log n) time and then iterate though the array in O(n) time to compare adjacent points. Unfortunately, I cannot think of a way to sort the points globally. I think the sort order is non-transitive, or rather, non-commutative.

Comment: This number of columns is not fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You have *N* rows of data with *M* columns each. Your solution is O(*M* · *N* ²) with O(1) space. The code below is O(*M* · *N* log *N*), but it needs O(*N* ²) extra space, so it is probably not a very practical solution. But it does speed up the process for large *N*.

First, I'll assume that all lines are different. (That makes explaining the algorithm easier, but I'll get back to that later.)

We can compare the two values in column *k* of two rows *r* and *s*. If *r*<sub>*k*</sub> ≤ *r*<sub>*k*</sub>, *r* "dominates" *s* in *k*. A row *r* must be deleted if there is an "all-dominating" row *s* that dominates *r* for all *k*.

We can find the "domination" for each column *k* by sorting the rows by the values in that column. A row *r* dominates *s* in *k*, if *n* comes before *s* in the sorted table.

As a simple example, imagine that you have one row whose values are smaller than all other values for all rows. That node dominates all other nodes, which are to be deleted. In all sorted tables, this node will be the first one.

Let's look at your example, sorted by the three columns:

```
 2     0.2470  0.6872  1.9626     5 ▼   0.9072  0.6268  0.6684     4     1.2874  1.5664  0.2470
 0     0.3072  1.1262  1.5706     7 ○   0.9072  0.6268  0.8706     5 ▼   0.9072  0.6268  0.6684
 8     0.3072  1.1262  1.5706     6 ○   1.3164  0.6506  1.8462     7 ○   0.9072  0.6268  0.8706
 1     0.5068  1.0630  0.9470     2     0.2470  0.6872  1.9626     1     0.5068  1.0630  0.9470
 5 ▼   0.9072  0.6268  0.6684     1     0.5068  1.0630  0.9470     0     0.3072  1.1262  1.5706
 7 ○   0.9072  0.6268  0.8706     0     0.3072  1.1262  1.5706     8     0.3072  1.1262  1.5706
 3 ○   1.0686  1.1348  1.7506     8     0.3072  1.1262  1.5706     3 ○   1.0686  1.1348  1.7506
 4     1.2874  1.5664  0.2470     3 ○   1.0686  1.1348  1.7506     6 ○   1.3164  0.6506  1.8462
 6 ○   1.3164  0.6506  1.8462     4     1.2874  1.5664  0.2470     2     0.2470  0.6872  1.9626
```

The `○` marks nodes that should be deleted. Here, row 5 (`▼`) dominates all deletion candidates, rows 3, 6 and 7. In addition, row 1 dominates row 3.

We must now find a way to determine if there is an all-dominating row *a*(*r*) for each row  *r*. We can do that with a set **S**(*r*) that starts as the full set of rows, **R**. Whenever a row *s* is dominated by *r*, it is removed from that set. After processing all rows *k*, the set **S**(*r*) is the set of all-dominating rows of row *r*.

Step by step:

- let **S**(*r*) = **R** for each *r*, *r* ∈ **R**
- for each column *k*, *k* = 1, ..., *M*:

  - sort the table: index <sub>*k*</sub> (*r*) < index <sub>*k*</sub> (*s*)   ⇔   *r*<sub>*k*</sub> < *s*<sub>*k*</sub>
  - let **A** = ∅
  - for each index *i* = 0, ..., *N* in the sorted table R<sup>*k*</sup>:

    - *r* = R <sub>*i*</sub><sup>*k*</sup>
    - **S**(*r*) = **S**(*r*) ∩ **A**
    - **A** = **A** ∪ { *r* }
- mark all *r*, **S**(*r*) = ∅ for deletion.

The *M* sortings of the *N* rows give an overall time complexity of O(*M*  · *N* log *N*). The *N* sets **S**<sub>*i*</sub> make O(*N* ²) additional space.

A good way to represent a set of numbers from 1 to *N* is a bitarray, which means that a set **S**<sub>*i*</sub> takes ⌊*N* − 1⌋ / 8 bytes. I can't see any more eficient representation of the sets. They are not sparse, because they go from **R** to ∅. Other data structures may be more space efficient, but require longer times to look up.

Now about those duplicate rows: If we have two identical rows *r* and *s* with *r*<sub>*k*</sub> = *s*<sub>*k*</sub>, *k* = 1, ..., *M*, there are two cases:

- there exists another row *a* that all-dominates *r* and *s*: then, *r* and *s* should both be deleted.
- there is no other all-dominating row: *r* and *s* should both be kept.

The first case is taken care for by the algorithm already. The second case can be taken care of by using a stable sorting algorithm. A stable sorting algorithm does not change the order of identical items when sorting. (C's `qsort` is not guaranteed to be stable.)

Using a stable sort in our algorithm yields these properties:

- after sorting all rows, identical items will be adjacent to each other;
- If *r* and *s* are identical and *r* comes before *s* in the original table, it will come before (and "dominate") *s* in all tables.

When going through the list of row and the current row is identical to the previous row and the previous row was not deleted, keep this row, too.

If you don't make this extra test, but use a stable sorting algorithm, only the first of a set of suplicate rows will be kept. That seems a more natural requirement to me. (I assume the additional condition that at least one row must be different to delete a row is only there to rule out that two identical nodes cancel themselves out.)

Implementation in C (with hard-wired *N* and *M*):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

enum {
    N = 9,
    M = 3,
    S = (N / 8) + 1,
};

struct Ref {
    double *ref;
    unsigned index;
    unsigned order;
    uint8_t mask[S];
};

static unsigned cmp_index;

int refcmp(const void *pa, const void *pb)
{
    const struct Ref *a = pa;
    const struct Ref *b = pb;
    
    if (a->ref[cmp_index] == b->ref[cmp_index]) {
        return (a->order < b->order) ? -1 : 1;
    }
    
    return (a->ref[cmp_index] < b->ref[cmp_index]) ? -1 : 1;
}
    
void stable_refsort(struct Ref *ref, unsigned n, unsigned dim)
{
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        ref[i].order = i;
    }

    cmp_index = dim;    
    qsort(ref, n, sizeof(*ref), refcmp);
}

int same(const struct Ref a, const struct Ref b)
{
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < M; i++) {
        if (a.ref[i] != b.ref[i]) return 0;
    }
    
    return 1;
}

int main(void)
{
    double line[N][M] = {
        {0.3072, 1.1262, 1.5706},
        {0.1068, 1.0630, 0.9470},
        {0.2470, 0.6872, 1.9626},
        {1.0686, 1.1348, 1.7506},
        {1.2874, 1.5664, 0.2470},
        {0.9072, 0.6268, 0.6684},
        {1.3164, 0.6506, 1.8462},
        {0.9072, 0.6268, 0.8706},
        {0.3072, 1.1262, 1.5706}
    };
    struct Ref ref[N];
    uint8_t zero[S] = {0};
    int kept = 0;

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        ref[i].ref = line[i];
        ref[i].index = i;
        memset(ref[i].mask, ~0u, S);
    }
    
    for (unsigned dim = 0; dim < M; dim++) {
        uint8_t mask[S] = {0};
        
        stable_refsort(ref, N, dim);

        for (unsigned i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            unsigned s = S;
            unsigned k = ref[i].index;

            while(s--) ref[i].mask[s] &= mask[s];

            mask[k / 8] |= (1u << (k % 8));
        } 
    }

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        if (memcmp(ref[i].mask, zero, S)) {
            if (kept && same(ref[i - 1], ref[i])) {
                kept = 1;
            } else {
                printf("delete %u\n", ref[i].index);
                kept = 0;
            }
        } else {
            kept = 1;
        }        
    }
    
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, M Oehm
I really appreciate your answer
That's helpful!